# How to use TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR to get acceleration in global Z

Tags: android, transform

In my app I am using the accels sensor to calculate whether user is jumping irregardless of phones orientation.  So I am trying to use TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR to create rotation matrix, but after I multiple it against vector, values do not come out correctly.  As a test I am actually using the TYPE_GRAVITY_SENSOR values, as if the transforms are correct, Z should always show the gravity.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
       switch(event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:

            if (mRotationMatrix[0] != 0) {

                Matrix.multiplyMV(transformedGravity, 0,
                        mRotationMatrix, 0,
                        new float[]{event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2], 0}, 0);
                // If I tilt phone, and break in debugger, transformedGravity[2] is not 9.8, and [0] is something like 6mps.
            }
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix,
                    event.values);

            break;
        }
```